# What to do when every cell in an UITableView is unique?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an UITableView where each cell is unique in contents but similair for purpose and am unsure how to the make the cells. See the following image.
[image: Example Image]
The outline of the black box represents the table, which is seperated in rows. Each row has a variable height and contains a visual representation of different data.
I am having about 50 rows, with each row containing about 10 of those green/blue lines which exist of an 2UIViews and an UILabel. I am in no need of editing or deleting. The data is about ±30kB of JSON, which I convert into strongly typed objects.

---

So far I have identified the following approaches:

1. No dequeueing, saving each cell once constructed with it's correspondending data.
2. No dequeueing, not saving the cell but init'ing and reconstructing the visual representation completely from the data.

   Dequeuing is always better.
3. Dequeueing the cell via unique identifiers and otherwise construct it

   - Can this be done using unique identifiers or will I have to implement that myself?
4. Dequeueing the cell and reconstructing the visual representation completely from data.

I am fine with the visual representation not appearing on the tablecell immediately when scrolling, it would be fine to construct the cells on a worker thread and then add the contents of the cells when each cell is constructed.

What approach would be best fit, and considered acceptable? Or why would another approach be better?

Comment: Cell is never reconstructed in tableview they got reused, just send those data to reusable cells, However are you getting those data from a web service? Does worker thread has to wait for network call of the data is stored on device?

Comment: One of my biggest issue's was the actual data. In my opinion it is ugly JSON: each green line is a seperate element in an array, which is seperated from the actual row. They also come completely unordered and hence the height of a row is unknown untill all of the data is available. I am downloading the data from a webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of rows are

1. fixed
2. number of rows very small (memory footprint wise)

and each row rather unrelated, the Quick Way™ would be to preinitialized all cells and return  them as needed:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [myCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

However if there is a slight chance that your cells don't all fit into memory at once (remember all the background stuff that also adds up to your total available 22-25MB heap space), you should still consider going the slightly more verbose way and create the cells lazily when they are accessed the first time, then cache the result. Good news is that UITableView already does exactly that for you, just use the cell identifiers as intended.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyCell%d", indexPath.row];
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithCellIdentifier:identifier];
       [cell autorelease]; // if non-ARC
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I don't recommend using a nil identifier, as suggested by rocir. By providing a cell identifier of nil, you prevent UTTableViewController from caching the cell for you ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW2)). This generates additional overhead when your cell is scrolled out of the visible area and made visible again at a later stage when the user scrolls back. In this case, the cell might still be around, but there's no way for you to access it when tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called.

Comment: I am going do this approach. If I walk into performance issue's I will either draw directly onto the cell's surface, save the cell's controls within the datasource (yuck), or build the cell's content asynchronuously (e.g. branch of an nsoperation to make the neccesary view and then call `[cell setNeedsLayout];`) Will mark as answer if I either succeed, or no other acceptable answer is provided. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes reusing the cell can give us some problems when each one is unique. It depends on the case and I'm not sure how you're implementing that. What I did without causing any performance problems is passing nil in the identifier and constructing the cell every time.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

Just to make sure, this may cause performance issues depending on how you make your cell. But for simple purposes, it should work.

Comment: Isn't using nil as identifier worse than an unique identifier? Or does passing nil stop the tableview from keeping the cells in memory? If I would pass an unique I might have the chance that sometimes it will be the correct cell, right?  
The approach @rocir mentions would be the second. I need to construct the horizontal colored lines with text for every row shown, let's call that view 'EventView'. For an EventView to know it's starting point and width I have to convert 2 dates to floating point values, representing x-coordinates of the view.
I am fine with queueing this on another thread.